# Online updating for ALS recommendation system

Tags: apache-spark-mllib, collaborative-filtering

Is there a way to export the spark ALS model after its being trained, into a PMML model or whatever format, which can be called outside of spark environment?

E.g., in JAVA, given a customer id C and a product id P, load the model file created by SCALA program, and call it, it will output a score for (C,P).

The major reason for this question is that when the size of the active user is huge, say 0.1 billion users over 100 products, the prediction size will be 10 billion. And item-based recommendation is not an option in our case.

Not sure how people in the industry do that, especially when there is a need to update the model daily which is trained by the previous whole month/week data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to save your model within the sprakenvironment, like this `ALSmodel.save("myModelPath")`. With this model you are able to score all known customer/item pairs.

I guess if you want to score outside of spark you have to export the item & user factors into another system and calculate the mf yourself. There you are also able to update user iteractions for your recommendations.

With `ALSmodel.userFactors` and `ALSmodel.itemFactors` you are able to extract the factors of your model.

Why would you want to score outside of spark? You can just simply precalculate your predictions and serve them online. If you want to update the recommendations on a very high frequenzy level you have to go the suggested way. If you want to update your model only on a daily basis I would suggest that you simply retrain the model every.